# How to retrieve raw values from mongoDB using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongoDB and Node.js and my JSON like :

```
[ [ { _id: 5874e9cf97a7f81db1fff5ca,
  createdAt: Tue Jan 10 2017 06:03:59 GMT-0800 (PST),
  pulses: 75 },
{ _id: 5874ea0173a3071dbd4ed5df,
  createdAt: Tue Jan 10 2017 06:04:49 GMT-0800 (PST),
  pulses: 75 },
{ _id: 5874eb138252e01de9737e07,
  createdAt: Tue Jan 10 2017 06:09:23 GMT-0800 (PST),
  pulses: 75 },
{ _id: 5875f89d375be10b42c08749,
  createdAt: Wed Jan 11 2017 01:19:25 GMT-0800 (PST),
  pulses: 75 },
{ _id: 5875f8d49f08d00b4e9d2117,
  createdAt: Wed Jan 11 2017 01:20:20 GMT-0800 (PST),
  pulses: 75 },
{ _id: 5876079811de080d2c7e59f1,
  createdAt: Wed Jan 11 2017 02:23:20 GMT-0800 (PST),
  pulses: 75 } ] ]
```

I want to retrieve only the values 75 in filed pulses. In mongo site, I see `find()` and `findOne()` but they do not show what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**find()**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) to get all the docuemnts with `{pulses: 75}` like :

```
db.collection.find({pulses: 75});
```

Or,
    Use [**findOne()**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) to get all the documents with `{pulses: 75}` like :

```
db.collection.findOne({pulses: 75});
```

If you just want to see only the `pulses` field in the results , add [**projection**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) as shown below :

```
db.collection.find({pulses: 75}, {pulses:1})
```

Assuming your outer array key is `pulsesArray`, for nested arrays, you can do like this:

```
db.collection.find({pulsesArray.0.pulses: 75});
```

Comment: Oh. In that case, whats the key of the main array ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check that and confirm.

Comment: thank you! the last line it is not working  `db.collection.find({pulsesArray.0.pulses: 75});` `SyntaxError: Unexpected number
`

Comment: @IstabraqMahmood I've just tested it in my local db, it is working fine.